# what can I pass [SomeType] to "paramName: SomeType = []" swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm pretty new to swift, trying to get authorization from user.

to request multiple auth at once, I gathered multiple options as array, and trying to request.

```
let variableArray = [UNAuthorizationOptions.badge, UNAuthorizationOptions.alert]
// error: Cannot convert value of type '[UNAuthorizationOptions]' to expected argument type 'UNAuthorizationOptions'
try! await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: variableArray)


//these works.        
try! await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert])
try! await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: .badge)
```

so I checked `requestAuthorization`, and found this:

```
open func requestAuthorization(options: UNAuthorizationOptions = []) async throws -> Bool
```

I think it takes both `UNAuthorizationOptions` and `[UNAuthorizationOptions]` but compiler says

> "hey, you are trying to pass `[UNAuthorizationOptions]` but I need
> `UNAuthorizationOptions`!"

how can I append `variableArray` above code to requestAuthorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `UNAuthorizationOptions` conforms to the protocol `OptionSet` and an `OptionSet` can be initialised using an array literal, that is [...] which is something different than your `variableArray` which is an `Array` object.

So this is why you can do both

```
try! await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert])
try! await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: .badge)
```

because one takes an `UNAuthorizationOptions` and the other one an `OptionSet` of `UNAuthorizationOptions`

You will find that this is quite a common pattern in swift when passing options or similar to functions in UIKit, AppKit, Foundation etc

Comment: thanks, there are so many underlying hidden features in swift...

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly specify the type of your `variableArray` as `UNAuthorizationOptions`. Replace `variableArray` with:

```
let variableArray: UNAuthorizationOptions = [UNAuthorizationOptions.badge, UNAuthorizationOptions.alert]
```

Comment: Note that when you do this you don't need to write out UNAuthorizationOptions on the right side of the = which makes the code a bit easier to read.